# How to Add user when creating docker image from alpine base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I want to add user **www-data** as my default user when I run my container in bash mode.

Currently, when I type WHOAMI then it's showing **root** as user, but I need **www-data** as user, how to do this in docker.

[image]

This is my docker file:

```
    FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

LABEL maintainer="y.ghorecha@abc.de" \
      muz.customer="xxx" \
      muz.product="WIDC" \
      container.mode="production"

#https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .deps autoconf tzdata build-base libzip-dev mysql-dev gmp-dev \
            libxml2-dev libpng-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev jpeg-dev icu-dev openldap-dev libxslt-dev &&\
    docker-php-ext-install zip xml mbstring json intl gd pdo pdo_mysql iconv soap \
                           dom gmp fileinfo sockets bcmath mysqli ldap xsl &&\
    echo 'date.timezone="Europe/Berlin"' >> "${PHP_INI_DIR}"/php.ini &&\
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime &&\
    echo 'Europe/Berlin' > /etc/timezone &&\
    apk del .deps &&\
    apk add --no-cache libzip mysql libxml2 libpng zlib freetype jpeg icu gmp git subversion libxslt openldap \
            apache2 apache2-ldap apache2-proxy libreoffice openjdk11-jre ghostscript msttcorefonts-installer \
            terminus-font ghostscript-fonts &&\
    ln -s /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2/modules &&\
    ln -s /usr/sbin/httpd /etc/init.d/httpd &&\
    update-ms-fonts

# imap setup
RUN apk --update --virtual build-deps add imap-dev
RUN apk add imap
RUN docker-php-ext-install imap

# copy all codebase
COPY ./ /var/www

# SSH setup
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache \
    openssh-keygen \
    openssh

# copy Azure specific files
COPY backend/build/azure/backend/ /var/www/backend/

# User owner setup
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

# Work directory setup
WORKDIR /var/www

# copy apache httpd.conf file
COPY httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

# copy crontabs for root user
COPY backend/data/CRONTAB/production/crontab.txt /etc/crontabs/www-data

# SSH Key setup
RUN mkdir -p /home/www-data/.ssh
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www-data/

#https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/3ebff8dadf1e38dbe694ea0b8f379f6b8bcd993e/2.4/alpine/httpd-foreground
#https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/alpine3.10/fpm/Dockerfile

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid && /usr/sbin/crond start && httpd -DBACKGROUND && php-fpm"]
```

Please advice on above.

Comment: What have you already tried?  I'd advise to not try running an ssh daemon inside a Docker container at all; the security issues around it are tricky and you shouldn't routinely need a shell in the container anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line to you dockerfile in order to become the `www-data` user

```
USER www-data
```

This can be either added

- in **the end** of your file (if you want at to become that user before the script exits), or
- in **the beginning** if you want to perform your actions within the docker file as this user.

Comment: where to write www-data??

Comment: in the end of your file if you want at the end of operation to become that user, or before you want to perform a certain action, check my updated answer

Comment: I am really glad I could help you @YogiGhorecha

Answer (score 5):

I'd start with first checking if the `www-data` user even exits in the image. Execute in the running container something like:

```
sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data
```

If the user *does exist* then add the [`USER www-data`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) directive to the Dockerfile after all commands that do installs, create directories, change permissions, etc. It would be required to also add `USER 0` at the beginning to switch to the root user for those commands if the base image doesn't run as root. Looking at the Dockerfile I'd suggest to add `USER www-data` before the `CMD` directive.

If the `www-data` user *doesn't exist* then it has to be added first. The commands for Alpine Linux are [addgroup](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user#addgroup) and [adduser](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user#adduser). Something like these if the user id for `www-data` is to be 33 and the group it belongs to is also named `www-data` and has id of 33:

```
RUN addgroup -S -g 33 www-data \
 && adduser -S -D -u 33 -s /sbin/nologin -h /var/www -G www-data www-data
```

Add the above just before `RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`, or make it a single `RUN` directive:

```
RUN addgroup -S -g 33 www-data \
 && adduser -S -D -u 33 -s /sbin/nologin -h /var/www -G www-data www-data \
 && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

Comment: Good work on explaining "how that supposed to work" and not only "how to quick-fix it"

Comment: @gears I'm using 7.2-fpm-alpine which is already have www-data user, check this https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/9bcb75e9dbd3a0ebafe3f825297724df30e3b254/7.2/alpine3.10/fpm/Dockerfile

Comment: **Error:** `Step 13/20 : RUN addgroup -S -g 33 www-data  && adduser -S -D -u 33 -s /sbin/nologin -h /var/www -G www-data www-data  && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
 ---> Running in 5b3a56e2ace8
addgroup: group 'www-data' in use
The command '/bin/sh -c addgroup -S -g 33 www-data  && adduser -S -D -u 33 -s /sbin/nologin -h /var/www -G www-data www-data  && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: @YogiGhorecha yes, "addgroup: group 'www-data' in use" error is to be expected if the `www-data` group exists already. My answer is split into two parts depending on whether the `www-data` user exists or not.